# How to convert an array of string to an array of objects using jsonata?

Tags: transform, jsonata

I have an array of strings:

```
"Street": ["10 First Avenue","Third Floor"]
```

That I would like to convert to an array of objects using jsonata:
https://try.jsonata.org/

```
"street": [
    {
        "attributes": {"line": "1"},
        "text": "10 First Avenue"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {"line": "2"},
        "text": "Third Floor"
    }
]
```

I have it working when I assume a fixed length but there is variance and I'm not sure how to grab the index.

I have it workable using

```
Street @ $street.$.[
    {
        "attributes": {"line": "1"},
        "text": $street
    }
]
```

But I still don't have the line number

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the position in the sequence using the `#` operator.  It's a number, so you'll need to cast it to  a string if that's what you need:

```
Street @ $street #$i.{
    "attributes": {"line": $string($i+1)},
    "text": $street
}
```

See https://try.jsonata.org/Q5Tt46GBT